# Problem with sendFile method and CDN Services

Tags: reactjs, getstream-io

It seems the service its returning **400 and Error when parsing request** output when the files are kinda big (Well not at all, because i'm trying to upload a 505kb .zip and its returning me an error), any kind of solution about this? Seems to be a random stuff because i upload a .pdf with a size of lets say 244KB and it returns error and then i try to upload a pdf with a size of 300kb and it goes fine, seems the CDN endpoint is having a strange behaviour, its also me happening with the images but not with the same frequency as the files.

Anyone have any kind of fix for this or idea why its happening?

I tried used postman and nodejs code and the results are always the same

```
try {
const response = await channel.sendFile(fs.createReadStream('file.pdf'),'file.pdf');
console.log(response);
} catch(e) {
console.log(e)
}
}

The process is returning the following
{ FetchError: invalid json response body at https://chat-us-east-1.stream-io-api.com/channels/messaging/XXXXXXX/file?api_key=XXXXXX reason: Unexpected token E in JSON at position 0
at /Users/user/Desktop/react-stream-chat-nodejs/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:272:32
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
message:
'invalid json response body at https://chat-us-east-1.stream-io-api.com/channels/messaging/XXXXXX/file?api_key=XXXXXX reason: Unexpected token E in JSON at position 0',
type: 'invalid-json' }
```

Comment: Hi Dvertov, this was a known bug and should be fixed now! can you try again?